# Getting Ajax Cart Pro to work with Quick View Pro

Tags: extensions, ajax

I'm using commercial modules [AJAX Cart Pro by aheadWorks](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-cart-pro-by-aheadworks.html) and [Quick View Pro by BelVG](http://store.belvg.com/quick-view-110.html) but I'm having an issues getting the two to work together.

When the quick view modal opens up, clicking the add to cart button doesn't trigger the ajax.  Instead, it submits the form normally and redirects the customer to the cart page.

How can I get the ajax cart to work in the quick view window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax Cart Pro uses their own version of javascript observers to detect events and fire their custom action instead.  You can find these observers in `js/aw_ajaxcartpro/observers/`.  Because your HTML is being loaded after page load, the observers aren't tracking the form submission.

This can most easily be solved by adding your own observer when the quick view window template is loaded.  Copy `base/default/template/belvg/quickviewpro/popup.phtml` to your package/theme.  You'll need to add your observer object to `AW_AjaxCartPro` by using `AW_AjaxCartPro.registerObserver()` (we can pretty much copy the observer in `js/aw_ajaxcartpro/observers/clickOnAddToCartInProductPage.js`).

Quickview uses a variable called `q_productAddToCartForm` which can be used in the observer method `_getTargetObj()`, and another variable `quickview` which can be used to close the modal once the form is submitted (after validation).

Long story short, add the following to your `popup.phtml` template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var AW_AjaxCartProObserverObject = new AW_AjaxCartProObserver('clickOnAddToCartInQuickview');
Object.extend(AW_AjaxCartProObserverObject, {

    uiBlocks: ['progress', 'options', 'add_confirmation'],

    _oldSubmitFn: null,

    /**
     * This method will be called when the observer is registered.
     * Here's where we'll inject our submit instead
     */
    run: function() {
        var targetObj = this._getTargetObj();
        if (!targetObj) {
            return null;
        }
        // Save the old submit
        this._oldSubmitFn = targetObj.form.submit;
        // Do ours instead
        targetObj.form.submit = this._observeFn.bind(this);
        //HACK for EE
        targetObj.form.select('button').each(function(btn){
            btn.removeAttribute('disabled')
        });
        return null;
    },

    stop: function() {
        var targetObj = this._getTargetObj();
        if (!targetObj) {
            return;
        }
        targetObj.form.submit = this._oldSubmitFn;
    },

    fireOriginal: function(url, parameters) {
        var targetObj = this._getTargetObj();
        if (!targetObj) {
            return;
        }
        this.stop();
        targetObj.submit();
    },

    _observeFn: function() {
        var targetObj = this._getTargetObj();
        if (!targetObj) {
            return;
        }
        var action = targetObj.form.readAttribute('action') || '';
        var params = targetObj.form.serialize(true);
        quickview.close();
        this.fireCustom(action, params);
    },

    _getTargetObj: function() {
        return q_productAddToCartForm;
    }
});
AW_AjaxCartPro.registerObserver(AW_AjaxCartProObserverObject);
delete AW_AjaxCartProObserverObject;
// Restart observers
AW_AjaxCartPro.stopObservers();
AW_AjaxCartPro.startObservers();
//]]>
</script>
```

Or, Quick View Pro was kind enough to leave you a method if you wanted to include/extend it there instead

```
# js/belvg/quickviewpro/quickView.js
Quickview.prototype   = {
    [...]
    /* Your code after quickview display */
    showAfterYourCode: function(pro_id) {

    },
    [...]
}
```